# simple routing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have the following two files in Angular, wanting to create a simple Login application. The first one is Login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> AngularJS Login SPA</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="mainApp">
        <div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
            <form action="/" id="myLogin">
                Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ng-model="username"><br/>
                Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password"><br/>
                <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the second one is controller.js:

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when ('/', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
.when ('#/dashboard',{
    resolve:{
        "check":function($location, $rootScope){
            if (!$rootScope.loggedIn)
            {
                $location.path('/dashboard');
            }
            else{

            }
        }
    },
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'

})
.otherwise ({
    redirectTo: '/'
})
});

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location, $rootScope){
$scope.submit = function(){


    if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin')
    {
        $rootScope.uname = $scope.username;
        $rootScope.password = $scope.password;
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    }
    else{
        alert('wrong stuff');
    }
};
});
```

The thing is after I succesfully enter the texts 'admin' and 'admin' on username and password (if I click otherwise it correctly shows me an alert), the address changes to .../index.html#/dashboard but it doesn't load me the page dashboard.html, a simple page I created for this app, located in the same folder where index.html is.

Any idea on how it can show me dashboard.html after I succesfully login with the two texts?
Any help could be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem.
I had to test the application in Mozilla because Google Chrome doesn't support SPAs (Single Page Applications) that can match a running server.